# php-cpp zend/php.h not found

Tags: php, c++, macos, php-cpp

I wanted to test the php-cpp possibilities but while using "make" it throughs "php.h"  missing at me:

```
g++ -Wall -c -g -std=c++11 -fpic `php-config --includes` -o zend/base.o zend/base.cpp
In file included from zend/base.cpp:8:
zend/includes.h:35:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include <php.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [zend/base.o] Error 1
```

How can I fix it? I`m on osx10.9.3 and if it's relevant I'm using xampp for php projects. The documentation of php-cpp http://www.php-cpp.com/documentation/install.

Comment: Make sure php.h is where it's supposed to be

Comment: @ElefantPhace do I have to download the whole php library for this? Just downloaded the php src and I'm adding missing file but right now it says `zend/includes.h:35:10: error: 'php.h' file not found with <angled> include; use
      "quotes" instead
#include <php.h>`

Comment: Oke, apparently what you need to do is download the php source from:

 - http://nl3.php.net/downloads.php

Copy the "zend" folder from the package and paste it to the php-cpp folder (delete the old one and rename the new one to "zend").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oke, apparently what you need to do is download the php source from: - nl3.php.net/downloads.php Copy the "zend" folder from the package and paste it to the php-cpp folder (delete the old one and rename the new one to "zend").

Answer (score 1):

First check if your "**php**" package is installed ... if not please install it.

Now get your php version with "**$php -v**" then maybe the "**php.h**" it already in your "**php/main/**" folder "**/usr/include/php/main/**" and put the "**php.h**" from there in the "**usr/include/**" directory.

If you cant find the "**php.h**" file there -
Just download the php sourcecode from github but you have to notice that you download the version which is similar to yours "**$php -v**".

Here go to the "**main**" directory in the php sourecode. There the is the "**php.h**" file located - now just put it in your "**usr/include/**" path.